# Set database connection string at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, connection-string

I am working on a MVC 4 web site. It should allow the user to select which database to be connected with depending on user selection from the View. All the databases have the same table structure and schema etc.

I have a database ConnectionString defined in the Web.config file that allows for connection to the first database.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DATABSE_SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I also used Linq DataContext to initialize connection to the database. Table mappings were all automatically generated by Linq to SQL in MVC 4.

```
public NEMP_DataDataContext() : 
            base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LINQ to SQL, you just create the Context with the connection string:

```
DataContext myContext = new DataContext(customConnectionString);
```

You don't need to worry about closing them or anything.  SQL Server is handling all that for you.  So you simply adjust the connection string slightly (Database Name) and create a new context based on whatever variable in every page you need to use the Context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ChangeDatabase` method of `SqlConnection`

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you should have a storage to get all of the database connections.
   Maybe the storage is a xml file or a simple database.
   But you need to implement how to get the connection strings.
2. If you have used EntityFramework for your dataconext in your applicaiton.
   You could have a constructor like the folowing code:

   ```
   public ApplicationDbContext(string nameOfConnection)
       : base(nameOfConnection)
   {
       this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
       this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
   }
   ```
3. Please invoke the 1 and get the nameOfConneciton, then invoke 2 to initialize the DbContext.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using EF but LINQ instead.

Comment: But the theory is the same. You can try it like this way.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully. But I assume you ask us that you want to let the user select the database they want to connect to. Then set the connection string.

Here's my solution, for example if you have 5 database to let user to select. You write those 5 connection string into web.config. Then make something like a drop down list or radio button that let's user to select database. And then make a if statement. For example if the first radio button is selected then

```
String connection string=connection.string["the name of connection string in web.confug"];
```

I hope this help you